# Is it possible for a normal human to live on a planet with two moons and a 429-days year, and what would the central star be like?

Tags: planets, stars

Just like the question, in my writing I need a planet with two moons and a 429-day year. What would be that planet be like in general? Can normal average size humans live there? Would the central star of that system be similar to ours?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A planet with multiple moons has nothing to do with the sun it is orbiting.  Mars has 2 small moons.  Earth one large one.  Other planets have many.

Humans could live on Mars and it has a year about 687 earth days long.  It does mean that your planet would be orbiting a sun at a distance in between earth and Mars, a little closer to Earth's.  The seasons would be longer but overall those parameters wouldn't affect humans living on it very much, unless you put a much larger or smaller sun in the middle.

Comment: Oh that's great, thank you so much. Can I describe times where both moons are visible, and times where none of them can be seen? is there a simulator or something that can help me understand the way this could work?

Comment: @DharienCthaeh The moons orbits would be different distances from the planet.  So one would go around the planet faster than the other one, this means that they would share the sky at times and others neither would be visible, while most of the time at least one would be in the sky.

Comment: That's great, Very, very thank you. This solves my general setting.

Comment: @DharienCthaeh The planet's distance from the sun can vary, so long as the planet rotates on its own axis 429 times for every orbit around the sun. The earth could have 429 days a year if it rotated 1.17 times faster. (I gave your answer an upvote though!)

Comment: @DharienCthaeh - also be aware that, if the overall temperature of your fictional is to be the same as our earth, and the year is 429 days long, the new earth is orbiting slightly farther from its sun, which means the sun needs to be a bit brighter.

Comment: Or the days can be shorter and the year the same length to fit 429 days into the same orbital distance as earth.

Comment: And some planets -- Venus, I'm looking at you -- have *no* moons. Of course, the planets in our solar system that have no moons aren't very habitable as they come, but with a bit of [terraforming](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terraforming)...

Answer (score 4):

The Earth itself, briefly, used to have more than 1,400 days in a year. The day [was only 6 hours long](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/earth-rotation-summer-solstice/) shortly after the moon was formed. A billion years ago there were 419 days in our year (due to the [20.9 hour day](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1997GeoRL..24..421W)).

It's clear then, that adding another small moon to the Earth itself would be the only requirement to create the situation you're asking for.

Comment: Even though I knew that, I made the dumb assumption of an 'approx' 24 hour day...

Comment: Yes, the idea is that a day should be not very different from a real day in earth.

Comment: @bowlturner I think a 24-hour day is a completely valid assumption.

Comment: @DharienCthaeh These were *real* days on the *real Earth*.

Comment: @Samuel well you still pointed out an excellent point I missed so +1!

Comment: Huh. Wonder what life will be like when days slow so much that basically one side of the planet is scorched and the other's frozen. I suppose we'll all have to live in the twilight lands... **edit:** Eugh. See, why did that woman have to ruin the perfectly good word that is "twilight". It was just uncommon enough, before, that now I can't help but think of the book-awfulness every time I use it.

Comment: @ParthianShot It won't ever happen. At the current rate, the day will only be about 30 hours long in a billion years' time when the sun has heated up enough that the Earth is uninhabitable. And even if the Earth were to survive into the very far distant future, it would be tidally locked to the Moon and not to the sun, and so it would still rotate once every few hundred hours (the Moon would also have receded further from the Earth, and so the month/day would be longer than it is now) and there would be no permanent twilight areas.